# Exclude folder names that start with or contain certain

Tags: vbscript

I found this code which excludes specific folder names, but I need to exclude based on folder names that 'start with'.

(example admin%) How do I re-write for that way?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\")
Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders
For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    If objSubfolder.Name <> "All Users" And objSubfolder.Name <> "Default" _
        And objSubfolder.Name <> "Default User" And objSubfolder.Name       <> "Public" Then
    WScript.echo objSubfolder.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you need.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\")
Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders
For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    If InStr(1,objSubfolder.Name, "admin") <= 0 Then
        WScript.echo objSubfolder.Name
    End If
Next
```

The above script should exclude all folders starting with **admin** or containing **admin**. It's case sensitive though. If you need to make it case insensitive use the below script.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\")
Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders
For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    If InStr(1,objSubfolder.Name, "admin",1) <= 0 Then
        WScript.echo objSubfolder.Name
    End If
Next
```